# Get sum from nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, tree

I have a tree structure formed by arrays in PHP, these trees have the following structure.

```
 array(5) {
["guid"]=>
string(32) "bfd08465daebc6a624f81fb38fdcb357"
["name"]=>
string(7) "Activos"
["parent_guid"]=>
string(32) "3caed17eb39d20aa9d409f2e61d457ff"
["suma"]=>
NULL
["children"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["guid"]=>
    string(32) "c0227d82bf3926d0517a0cffce66be31"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Current Assets"
    ["parent_guid"]=>
    string(32) "bfd08465daebc6a624f81fb38fdcb357"
    ["suma"]=>
    NULL
    ["children"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["guid"]=>
        string(32) "c7bc90c45a5319a00f8a64c7ae1a5ca9"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Cuenta de ahorro"
        ["parent_guid"]=>
        string(32) "c0227d82bf3926d0517a0cffce66be31"
        ["suma"]=>
        string(11) "111035.3800"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["guid"]=>
        string(32) "72a3ed3467cfd24671197ad7d7f9bb40"
        ["name"]=>
        string(17) "Cuenta de cheques"
        ["parent_guid"]=>
        string(32) "c0227d82bf3926d0517a0cffce66be31"
        ["suma"]=>
        string(6) "0.0000"
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
```

If a node has children, then the index "children" will have a nested array containing values. The question here is, how do I sum all values in index "suma" for every children given a "guid"?

For example, given guid c7bc90c45a5319a00f8a64c7ae1a5ca9 the function must returns 111035.3800 since this subtree has no children. But with c0227d82bf3926d0517a0cffce66be31 the function must sum Null + 111035.3800 + 0.0000 which are the values in index "suma" for the given guid and its repective children. If a node has 'n' nested children then the function should iterate through all child and sum the value in index "suma".

I've already have a recursive function which returns a subtree given an guid value but I don't know how to work the sum.

```
function getChildrenAccounts($array, $parent_guid)
  {
    if(!is_array($array))
      return null;
    if(isset($array['guid']) && $array['guid'] == $parent_guid)
      return $array['children'];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $return = $this->getChildrenAccounts($item, $parent_guid);
      if (!is_null($return)) 
        return $return;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code :**

```
function getChildrenSum($array)
{
    $sum = 0;

    if (count($array)>0)
    {
        foreach ($array as $item)
        {
            $sum += $item['suma'];
            $sum += getChildrenSum($item['children']);
        }
    }
    else return 0;
}

function getSumFromArray($array,$guid)
{
    foreach ($array as $item)
    {
        if (isset($item['guid']))
            if ($item['guid']==$guid)
                return getChildrenSum($item['children']);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Usage :**

```
$total = getSumFromArray($array,"c0227d82bf3926d0517a0cffce66be31");
```

Comment: Thanks, just for the record I had to use mySQL function 'COALESCE' in the query that brings up the tree to avoid NULL values in index "suma"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your function definition. You have not decided what your function will do.

```
//What is the return value here?
function getChildrenAccounts($array, $parent_guid) {
```

If the answer to that is 'many things' then you have a problem. In your case you have 'null', an array, and probably a value (sum of the 'suma' field).

I recommend writing a function:

```
function sumChildrenAccounts($array, $parent_guid, &$sum) {
  if(!is_array($array)) { return null; }//this needs to be caught as an error!
  if(isset($array['guid']) && $array['guid'] == $parent_guid) { //a valid array
    foreach ($array['children'] as $child) {
      $sum = $this->sumChildrenAccounts($child, $parent_guid, $sum) + $array['suma'];
    }
    return $sum;
  }
  return null;//also an error!!!
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel I want the sum value but also guid, name, parent guid and suma for parent node. I want to display the name of the parent and the sum for parent and all children.